# How can I delete a sound when the sound is stopped?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-playsound

Can I remove an audio file when it stopped with playsound module? I have written a code but I can't do it:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound

def say(textg):
    tts = gTTS(text=textg, lang='en')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    playsound('audio.mp3')
    time.sleep(here, what i have to do?)
    os.remove('audio.mp3')
```

I am using Python 2.7.15

Comment: It doesn't look like `playsound` has a function to do this. have you tried `playsound(None)`? You could always create an empty or silent audio file and play that to "stop" the sound.

Comment: Did any other module have the functionality to do this? Any suggestions!

Comment: `Pygame` has the ability to start and stop audio. Take a some time to learn how Pygame works then take a look at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop audio with playsound module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158779/how-to-stop-audio-with-playsound-module)

Answer (score 0):

`playsound` is the name of module, you should use `playsound.playsound`(which is a function name) instead:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound

def say(textg):
    tts=gTTS(text=textg,lang='en')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    playsound.playsound('audio.mp3')
    os.remove('audio.mp3')
```

After calling `playsound.playsound`, the program will wait until it finishes.