# How to stop audio with playsound module?

Tags: python, python-playsound

How do I stop the audio playing through playaudio module in Python code?
I have played music but I can't stop that music. How can I stop it?

```
playsound.playsound("name_of_file")
```

Comment: You will need to show us some more code. This is very little to work with.

Comment: like i have one file named drinking_water.mp3 then i want to stop the music when i inputs stop then i am not able to stop the music . i enter the code playsound.playsound("drinking_water.mp3") but i want to stop the music in middle, then what should be the code for stopping that playing music

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) is a single function module that plays sounds, and nothing else.  It would seem that means it does not stop playing sounds either.  From their own documentation:

> The playsound module contains only one thing - the function (also named) playsound.

Personally, I like to use [pyaudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/).  The following code is adapted from the example [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/). The code plays audio and has the space bar set as a pause/play button.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
from pynput import keyboard

paused = False    # global to track if the audio is paused
def on_press(key):
    global paused
    print (key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.space:
        if stream.is_stopped():     # time to play audio
            print ('play pressed')
            stream.start_stream()
            paused = False
            return False
        elif stream.is_active():   # time to pause audio
            print ('pause pressed')
            stream.stop_stream()
            paused = True
            return False
    return False


# you audio here
wf = wave.open('audio\\songs\\And_Your_Bird_Can_Sing_mp3_2_wav.wav', 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# define callback
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

# open stream using callback
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

# start the stream
stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active() or paused==True:
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
    time.sleep(0.1)

# stop stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()

# close PyAudio
p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the multiprocessing module to play the sound as a background process, then terminate it anytime you want:

```
import multiprocessing
from playsound import playsound

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=("file.mp3",))
p.start()
input("press ENTER to stop playback")
p.terminate()
```

Comment: how to call terminate command from another file ?

Comment: this code is broken

Answer (score 5):

On windows try:
`import winsound`

```
winsound.PlaySound(r'C:\sound.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Stop Playback:

```
winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#pip install pygame
from pygame import mixer
import time
mixer.init() #Initialzing pyamge mixer

mixer.music.load('lovingly-618.mp3') #Loading Music File

mixer.music.play() #Playing Music with Pygame

time.sleep(5)


mixer.music.stop()
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much easier way:

```
wmp = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("WMPlayer.OCX")
wmp.settings.autoStart = True
wmp.settings.volume = 100
wmp.URL = file
while globals()["allowSound"]:
    PumpWaitingMessages()
```

You can change `globals()["allowSound"]` from another thread and set it to `False` when the audio has ended (you can get the length of the audio with `wmp.durationString`).

Here is some more info about this: [Windows Media Player COM Automation works from VBS but not from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157138/windows-media-player-com-automation-works-from-vbs-but-not-from-python)

Although this does not use the playsound module it is a good alternative.

Answer (score -1):

After successful execution of the program, audio file will start playing. Now Click on terminal, once you see the cursor, type `Ctrl+C`, it will bring you out of the terminal and audio will also stop playing.

Programming Instructions used:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('//path//to//a//sound//file//you//want//to//play.mp3')
```

Comment: That will stop the whole program, which may or may not be what the OP wants. The accepted answer seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

On your terminal tab, look for kill(delete) option on the right hand side.
Click the delete option and it will stop playing.