# How to pause / resume multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python

So I got an idea to build something like mp3 player. To build that, I used `multiprocessing` module provided in Python. Here is my code

```
import multiprocessing
from playsound import playsound

def cp():
    playsound('Music.mp3') # play the music

x = multiprocessing.Process(target = cp, daemon = True)

def main():
    x.start()
    while True and x.is_alive:
        u = input("Input: ")
        print(u)
        if u == "S":
            x.terminate()
            print("Terminated process")
            break
        elif u == 'P':
            # questioned code
            print("Process paused")
        elif u == 'R':
            # questioned code
            print("Process resumed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The idea is, when the program is executed, the program will automatically play the `Music.mp3` file. To control the program, the user must input specific keyword into it.

`S` to stop the music and exit the program

`P` to pause the music

`R` to resuming playing the music

For now, I only know how to code the `S` option. For the others, I don't have any idea how to code it. So my question is: Is there any idea how to complete the `P` and `R` options? Or maybe, is there any idea about how to build the program using another method besides using `multiprocessing` module?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158779/how-to-stop-audio-with-playsound-module

Comment: The Playsound library offers exactly one function: play a sound. No pause, resume or stop. You will need a lib with more features to reach your goal.

Comment: You could use os.kill with SIGSTOP and SIGCONT, but it seems really overkill. Have you any way to get the position of the current player? To restart at the given place? In such a case, you could stop the process and start it again at the previous position.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. But finally I found the solution for may problem. Instead of using multiprocessing and playsound module in python, im using pygame.music module to do the task. It has more usefull function than playsoung