# Getting an AssertionError when I use the multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-playsound

The relevant code is actually from a separate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158779/how-to-stop-audio-with-playsound-module).

Here it is anyway

```py
import multiprocessing
from playsound import playsound

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=("file.mp3",))
p.start()
input("press ENTER to stop playback")
p.terminate()
```

When I run this exact code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omit/Developer/omit/main2.py", line 22, in <module>
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(printStatus)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 82, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
(yt-proj) omit@omit-Air youtube proj % /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 "/Users/omit/Developer/omit/main2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omit/Developer/omit/main2.py", line 22, in <module>
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(printStatus)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 82, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you add a minimum reproducible example? Your code doesn't have a problem besides not checking if you are top level. Your error, on the other hand, shows a variable that is not in your code.

Comment: @2pichar My code looks exactly like the code above, except it uses a different mp3 file.

Comment: then what is this `p2` variable?

Comment: Right - completely missed that. You're right that I had a p2 variable in there somewhere

Answer (score 2):

The code to start the multiprocessing must never be "top level". It must only be run if this is the main thread.

```
def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=("file.mp3",))
    p.start()
    input("press ENTER to stop playback")
    p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, as seen in your error message is in the `p2` variable. You are creating it like this:

```py
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(printStatus)
```

That is a problem because the first positional argument is the `group` parameter. You need to change it to this:

```py
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=printStatus)
```

Here are the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) for `multiprocessing.Process`.

The relevant paragraph (emphasis mine):

> **class multiprocessing.Process(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)**
> Process objects represent activity that is run in a separate process. The Process class has equivalents of all the methods of threading.Thread.
> The constructor should always be called with keyword arguments. *group should always be None;* it exists solely for compatibility with threading.Thread. target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method.

As shown above, your problem is coming from trying to create a `Process` object without using keyword arguments, and it is assigning something to the `group` parameter.