# Cannot terminate `playsound`-process in python, sound keeps playing

Tags: python, python-playsound

I want to play a sound file for a certain period of time and stop playing it after this time period.
I used the playsound function of the playsound python module.
I created a process with playsound as target (module `multiprocessing`) in order to be able to terminate this process.
Starting the process works fine, sound begins to play.
But if I wait e.g. 5 seconds with `time.sleep(5)` and terminate the process, the sound keeps playing.
Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from playsound import playsound
import time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=('my_soundfile.mp3',))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    p.terminate()
```

So if I run this code, the sound file starts to play, but it does not stop playing after 5 seconds.
The sleep time period does not matter, same problem with other values.
If I terminate the process immediately after starting it

```
p.start()
p.terminate()
```

the sound file does not start playing, I assume because terminating the process works as intended.
But if I do something (e.g. waiting a period of time with time.sleep()) in between, the sound file keeps playing.

I have the idea of using multiprocessing in order to stop the sound file from playing from this post: [How to stop audio with playsound module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158779/how-to-stop-audio-with-playsound-module)
(I wanted to ask my question as a comment in this post, but I need a reputation of 50 for that...)

I know there are other ways to play a sound file in python, but I want to know why terminating this process does not stop the sound file from playing.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.6

Comment: I would guess that `playsound()` on your platform works by launching a separate sound-playing utility.  You have no control over that process, because you have no way of even knowing which process that is.  You need to use some other approach that, unlike `playsound`, is actually designed to give you ongoing control over the sound being played - `pygame`, perhaps.

Comment: `pyaudio` would be another possible option.  That being said, instead of trying to play just 5 seconds of a larger sound file, it would probably be better to make a clip of the source file that is the length you want to play, and then just use that smaller file.  From reading the `playsound` docs, it also looks like you could avoid multiprocessing by passing the `block=False` optional parameter to `playsound()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I want to mark this question as solved, here is the summary so far:

- As @jasonharper suggested, the problem here is that `playsound()` launches another program that plays the sound, terminating the original process won't have any effect on this new process.
- Possible solutions for this problem are (from the comments of @nigh_anxiety and @jasonharper):

  - use something else like `pyaudio` (which I did, works fine) or `pygame`
  - Shorten the original soundfile to the length I want it to play (that would work, but too much effort...)