# How to stop "playsound" in Python with esc key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program for an alarm to sound. It works, however, I want the user to be able to stop the sound by pressing the 'esc' key. I am not sure what kind of while loop to use or if I need to use the number 27 to denote the esc key.

How can I write a simple process for this, and where should it be inserted in the code?

```
from playsound import playsound
import time


CLEAR = "\033[2J"
CLEAR_AND_RETURN = "\033[H"


def alarm(seconds): 
    time_elapsed = 0

    print(CLEAR)
    while time_elapsed < seconds: 
        time.sleep(1)
        time_elapsed += 1

        time_left = seconds - time_elapsed
        minutes_left = time_left // 60 
        seconds_left = time_left % 60 

        print(f"{CLEAR_AND_RETURN}Alarm will sound in: {minutes_left:02d}:{seconds_left:02d}")


    playsound("alarm.mp3")

minutes = int(input("How many minutes to wait until alarm sounds?:"))
seconds = int(input("How many seconds to wait until alarm sounds?:"))
total_seconds = minutes * 60 + seconds
alarm(total_seconds)
alarm(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Playsound` isn't the best library to use for this, because it lacks the ability to stop playing sound. Once it's started, the only way for it to stop is for the file to end (according to the documentation).

One solution to this is to use `multiprocessing`, so you can stop the file at any time you want, without exiting the program. I'll be using the module `keyboard` to detect key presses:

```
from playsound import playsound
import multiprocessing
import keyboard

CLEAR = "\033[2J"
CLEAR_AND_RETURN = "\033[H"

def start(): #once alarm() is finished, now we start playing the sound
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=play)
    p.start()
    keyboard.add_hotkey(lambda: end(p), 'esc') #whenever we press esc, it calls the function end() with the argument p (which is our process)

def end(p):
    p.terminate() #makes the sound stop playing

def play():
    playsound("alarm.mp3")

def alarm(seconds): 
    time_elapsed = 0

    print(CLEAR)
    while time_elapsed < seconds: 
        time.sleep(1)
        time_elapsed += 1

        time_left = seconds - time_elapsed
        minutes_left = time_left // 60 
        seconds_left = time_left % 60 

        print(f"{CLEAR_AND_RETURN}Alarm will sound in: {minutes_left:02d}: 
{seconds_left:02d}")

    start()

minutes = int(input("How many minutes to wait until alarm sounds?:"))
seconds = int(input("How many seconds to wait until alarm sounds?:"))
total_seconds = minutes * 60 + seconds
alarm(total_seconds)
```

But...I did mention that `playsound` isn't the best module for this. It would be much better to use `pyaudio`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178541/23190147) stackoverflow post (I got the `multiprocessing` code from there) to see how to use `pyaudio`. `Pyaudio` allows you to play and stop the audio without the need for `multiprocessing`.